# What is the spectral radius of the operator $T_k:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ defined as $T_k x (t)= \int_0^1 k(t,s) x(s) ds$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

I would like to know the spectral radius of the operator $T_k$ from $C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ :
   $$T_k x (t)= \int_0^1 k(t,s) x(s) ds$$ 
where  $k(x,y)\colon [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb C$ is continuous.

And also although I know that $Tf(x)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$ is compact, I am not able to follow that $T_k$ is compact. Any hints and ideas ? 
Thanks!

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : Since the map is from $C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ and i know that the map $T(f)(s) =\int_0^s f(x)dx$ is compact , is there a reasoning by which i can immediatly say that $T_k$ is compact ?

Comment: An operator is compact only if it is the limit of finite rank operators. This is what Davide was suggesting. But you can also reason on the fact that $k$ is uniformly continuous on a compact..

Comment: I don't know. What you know is a special case; I'm not sure you can deal with the general one. But probably the proof of this case can be extended to the general one. Have you use Arzela-Ascoli theorem?

Comment: @uforoboa : yes , but can u tell me how does approximating $k$ as a limit of polynomials in $t,s$ have to do with the finite rank of $T_k$ . i think i am not understanding .

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : Yes, i used arzela ascoli to show that $\int f(s) ds  $ is compact .

Comment: @uforoboa What I suggest is to use the sentence you wrote without the "and only if". I would be true in the context of Hilbert spaces, but there are counter-example in Banach spaces (I think in works of Tzafriri).

Comment: So you can try to use it here.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Are you sure that it is a limit of finite-rank operators? Now that I think about it, I would be sure if the integral were not dependent on $t$. But here it is... Do you see my point? How would you overcome it?

Comment: @uforoboa I see, actually operators $f\mapsto (t\mapsto t^k\int_0^ts^jf(s)ds)$ are not finite-ranked (but compact, and the proof of this is quite the same as when we start from the general form of the kernel). So my first idea wasn't good.

Answer (score 1):

To show compactness, we can use Arzela-Ascoli's theorem. Let $B$ the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ of norm $\leqslant 1$. We have to show equi-continuity of $T_k(B)$. It follows from the fact that $k$ is *uniformly* continuous on $[0,1]^2$.

For the spectral radius, show by induction that 
$$\lVert T_k^p\rVert\leqslant\frac{\lVert k\rVert_\infty^p}{p!},$$
the spectral radius formula and [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103352/a-question-on-the-stirling-approximation-and-logn).

Comment: yes , i did it . Is $0$ spectrum of $T_k$ . it looks like that .